# Detecting Colors on object in OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

I am having an issue with color detection in OpenCV 3.4. I will present a picture of my problem below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 


img= cv2.imread("C:\\Users\Stefan_Cepa\\Desktop\\dataset2\\set\\A6.png")

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([30,150,150])
upper_range = np.array([255,255,180])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

while(True):
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see I've set my lower and upper bounds to detect Red color in an image, but for some reason, as you can see in image below, I am not getting any results. Any tips & tricks would be extremely helpful! Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Why the hue in 30 (that is 60 in the hue wheel) will give red? it looks more like yellowish... red will be more like 0 -15 and since it is at the beginning and end of the wheel, you should also get like 170-180.

Comment: Mixing hsv and bgr values  @api55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `hsv` colorspace but you are providing ranges of `bgr` values. they are incompatible.

For hsv:

> For HSV, Hue range is `[0,179]`, Saturation range is `[0,255]` and Value range is `[0,255]`. Different softwares use different scales. So if you are comparing OpenCV values with them, you need to normalize these ranges.
>   [source: docs.opencv.org/3.2.0](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html)

Your code almost looks like this: http://pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection. Only they use bgr.

**Solution:**

Convert your mask-ranges to hsv or load images as `bgr`.

Red on hsv is on hue 0 so you probably would need a combined mask of 170-180 hue  and 0-10 hue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've fixed it! I will mark this as accepted! But i have one more question. It is really hard to discriminate the color of the object and yellow color on the object. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could sample the color of the transistors body and create a very tight mask for it - if you have consistent lightning that "might" work. Else maybe you should try to get out geometrical featurs (edge detection) and try to isolate those small bands from bigger blobs - not sure, depends strongly on your image quality over time Not sure though, you have lots of reflection as well. If you can get clean edges with (Canny? ) you could invert the found edges and multiply them so you get thin black spacers around the edges on the image ... between rings and body

Comment: I think i understand but not sure how can i then detect color after using Canny ? Sorry if question is stupid i am new to OpenCV and computer vision in general . Thing is, when i detect color (e.g Red ) i need to know in program i've detected Red color on image. Because there is an equation dependent of color of bands on the object ( object is called resistior Resistor ) . Also, i need to know the ordering of detected colors ( e.g yellow is first band red is 2nd etc) . Any suggestions? And thank you a lot for your help by the way.

Comment: My cv times are past. Canny gives you a b/w picture - lots of black, few white lines.  threshold it so all  near to black values are 0 and all lighter values are 255. subtract this from your image and normalize your colorvalues if they drop below 0 ( or create a 0/1 mask and multiply it with your images bgr) - you should get 0 where the canny is white and your former colors where canny is black.

Comment: Or you inspekt this http://armageddon421.de/?p=279  and find that https://github.com/armageddon421/ResCan or this https://sites.google.com/site/ohmcalcucsb/ and take it from there...